# Scroll outside of UITableView frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uiatableview

How to scroll whole `UITableView` content outside of `UITableView` frame? 
Setting `table.scrollIndicatorInsets` does not let to scroll upwards and content disappear behind another view at the top.

Comment: I will probably end up putting everything above UITableView into a cell and place it inside as a first cell. This would allow the "real" UITableView content to scroll upwards and cover all screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

after loading of the view completed e.g after viewDidAppear:

```
CGFloat oldContentHeight = tableView.contentSize.height;
tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(tableView.contentSize.width, oldContentHeight + tableView.bounds.size.height);
```

Updated the answer.

Comment: Setting tableView.contentSize does not allow it's content to scroll out of the tableView frame bounds. It only makes content size bigger, which is presented only through scrollView frame.

Answer (score 2):

select Table view-> got to Attribute indicator -> tick on "Clip To Bounds".
Done

Answer (score 1):

As @Tushar pointed out setting the size of view might be the correct approach here, but double the size of the contentview, might be a bit overkill if you have a really long tableview. I would suggest adding the size of the current window instead.

```
CGFloat oldContentHeight = tableView.contentSize.height;
CGFloat windowHeight = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].frame.size.height);
tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(tableView.contentSize.width, oldContentHeight + windowHeight);
```